# vowel count in codeabbey

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm working on the [vowel counting problem at coedabbey](http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/vowel-count), but my solution doesn't seem to be working.  Here's what I'm doing:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(final String[] args){

        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int amount = input.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < amount ; i++){
            int sum = 0;
            String nowa = input.nextLine();

            for(int j = 0; j < nowa.length() ; j++){
                char x = nowa.charAt(j);

                if(x == 'a' || x == 'o' || x == 'u' || x == 'i' || x == 'e' || x == 'y'){
                    ++sum;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(sum+ " ");
         }
    }
}
```

But it does not do the right number of lines, and always outputs `0` for the count for a line after I enter the input.  After that it does one fewer line than I expected.

An example run might look as follows:

```
> java Solution
> 3
0
> hello
2
> george
3
```

But, I wanted to enter another line because I said "3" at the beginning.

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 2):

Skip a line after `nextInt()` as it doesnt consumes whole line it consumes only token

```
 int amount = input.nextInt();
 input.nextLine();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/K3h8iC)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `String nowa = input.nextLine();` try `String nowa = input.next();`.